# Rails is showing incorrect calculation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pry-rails

```
[8] pry(#<Plan>)> self[:total_outstanding]||0 / self.dd_amount 
=> 10100.0
[9] pry(#<Plan>)> self[:total_outstanding]||0
=> 10100.0
[10] pry(#<Plan>)> self.dd_amount
=> 900.0
[11] pry(#<Plan>)> self[:total_outstanding].to_i||0/self.dd_amount.to_i
=> 10100
```

self[:total_outstanding].to_i||0/self.dd_amount.to_i should reuturn 11 instead of 10100 which the value of the first attribute

I am trying to debug this in a pry session

When the code ran it did consider the value as 10100 which is just wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OR operator (`||`) has lower precedence than the division operator (`/`).

Ruby is interpreting your last line as this:

```
self[:total_outstanding].to_i || (0/self.dd_amount.to_i)
```

This will just return `self[:total_outstanding].to_i`, because it is a truthy value.

Group `self[:total_outstanding].to_i||0` together like this:

```
(self[:total_outstanding].to_i||0) / self.dd_amount.to_i
```

Comment: Operator `||` has a *lower* precedence than operator `/`, not higher. See [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Comment: But August's solution works.. and it looks more obvious now. But @user4235730 thanks for sharing the link.. quite helpful..